# Recursion in SQL Server function with cursor not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, recursion

This is the table structure.

```
select nid, memberid, sponsorid 
from tblmember;
```

Which produces the following result:

```
nid memerid sponsor
-------------------
1   679414  0
2   622411  679414
3   647964  679414
5   285631  679414
6   119979
```

I am trying to create a tree like structure where each node can have only three child nodes hence if the member with memberid `679414` introduces a new branch and he already has three child nodes then the new branch will be added to the first child node of `679414` if it has less than 3 child nodes. Sponsorid is the parent node's Memberid(which is unique). To find the first node in `679414`'s tree that has less than 3 child nodes I created the following function with cursor.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getSponsor (@id VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(101)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cou INT;
    DECLARE @id1 VARCHAR(200);

    SELECT @cou = count(*)
    FROM tblmember
    WHERE sponsorid = @id

    IF (@cou < 3)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE db_cursor LOCAL FOR
            SELECT memberid
            FROM dbo.tblmember
            WHERE sponsorid = @id

        OPEN db_cursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id1

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC getsponsor @id1;
        END

        CLOSE db_cursor
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor
    END

    RETURN '';
END
```

But this this cursor is not executed when I try it using the following code.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(200);
EXEC @a = [getSponsor] '679414'
SELECT @a;
```

Is there anything that I have done wrong? I checked online and saw that the cursor is global hence in recursion it causes problem so I put Local in cursor definition.

Comment: It looks like this is currently depth-first search (so, the first child of the first child of the first child would be selected before the second child if any of the first children has a space available, no matter what the depth). Is that really the desired ordering?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that as well. Can you suggest another algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the recursive common table expression for solving the problem. 
After calculating the node tree we just ignore the used nodes.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, 1 R FROM tblmember T WHERE sponsorid = @id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT T.id, T.memberid, T.sponsorid, R + 1 R FROM tblmember T INNER JOIN CTE ON T.sponsorid = CTE.memberid
)
,UsedNodes AS (
    SELECT sponsorid, R FROM CTE 
    GROUP BY sponsorid, R
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
)
SELECT TOP 1 @return_id = memberid 
FROM CTE 
WHERE memberid NOT IN ( SELECT sponsorid FROM UsedNodes )
ORDER BY R, id
```

Comment: brilliant. this doesn't work when the main parent has no child nodes but i can work around that. Thanks a lot